# How to build a theme using jaredpalmer/presspack with Google Maps integration?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wordpress-theming

### Introducing the problem

Building this theme using [jaredpalmer/presspack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/presspack) for docker, I'm struggling for a few days now as I try to insert this pair of Google Maps instances within an element that will be called in every page. The maps won't load and Chrome tells me my function is not there.

### Some context

Presspack is serving the DB and uses yarn to make a environment. It keeps scripts separately for general purposes and specific ones, as it has a common.js - where I code everything it should load on every page - and a .js - which loads only on specific pages. I'm working on common now, since I believe this contact section will be used on every page and blog post of this site. The calling function for this section is WP basic `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'contato-std' ); ?>`

I've added a code in functions.php to load the API key script after the footer of my pages.

It's important to mention that I've tried the js code I'm using in common.js on another HTML only environment.

### My files

**common.js**

```
 export default {
  init() {
    // JavaScript to be fired on all pages
    console.log('common');
  },
  finalize() {
  // JavaScript to be fired on all pages, after page specific JS is fired

    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isMobile) { // Tudo o que for pra navegadores mobile

    (...)


    } else { // Tudo o que for pra navegadores padrão

    (...)

    // GOOGLE MAPS LOAD
    var markers = [{
      GPS1: -15.7954901,
      GPS2: -47.8926766,
      client_address: "Corpus - Fisioterapia & Pilates, Unidade Asa Sul" 
    }];

    function initialize() {
      initMap();
      initMap2();
    };

    function initMap() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.7954901, -47.8926766); // default location
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP,
        mapTypeControl: true
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaAsaSul'), myOptions);
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, lat, lng;

      for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        lat = (markers[i].GPS1);
        lng = (markers[i].GPS2);
        name = (markers[i].client_address);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          name: name,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
          infowindow.setContent(this.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        }.bind(marker));
      }
    }
    var markers2 = [{
      GPS1: -15.7187167,
      GPS2: -47.8867326,
      client_address: "Corpus - Fisioterapia & Pilates, Unidade Lago norte"
    }];

    function initMap2() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.7187167, -47.8867326); // default location
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP,
        mapTypeControl: true
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaLagoNorte'), myOptions);
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, lat, lng;

      for (i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {
        lat = (markers2[i].GPS1);
        lng = (markers2[i].GPS2);
        name = (markers2[i].client_address);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          name: name,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
          infowindow.setContent(this.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        }.bind(marker));
      }
    }


  },
};
```

**function.php**

```php
<?php
...
function add_google_maps() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-google-maps',
        'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize',
        NULL,
        NULL,
        true
    );

    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

        if ( 'my-google-maps' !== $handle )
            return $tag;

        return str_replace( ' src', ' async defer src', $tag );

    }, 10, 2 );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_google_maps');

?>
```

The JS handling the routing from common.js and .js is **index.js**

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import './style.scss';

import Router from './util/Router';
import common from './routes/common';
import home from './routes/home';

/**
 * Populate Router instance with DOM routes
 * @type {Router} routes - An instance of our router
 */
const routes = new Router({
  /** All pages */
  common,
  /** Home page */
  home
  /** About Us page, note the change from about-us to aboutUs. */
});

/** Load Events */
jQuery(document).ready(() => routes.loadEvents());
```

### Bad response

It should load both instances of maps within the respective div's #mapaAsaSul and #mapaLagoNorte, but it won't and Chrome's console returns this:

```
(index):1 
Uncaught (in promise) Xc {message: "initialize is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Xc (http://maps.googleapis.com/ma…KEY&callback=initialize:125:107"}message: "initialize is not a function"name: "InvalidValueError"stack: "Error↵    at new Xc (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:56:227)↵    at Object._.Yc (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:56:337)↵    at Uh (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:125:221)↵    at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:125:107"__proto__: Error
Promise.then (async)
Vh @ js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:125
google.maps.Load @ js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:21
(anonymous) @ js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:212
(anonymous) @ js?key=KEY&callback=initialize:212
```

This *initialize* is written in common.js. The file is listed in console, red by webpack (which presspack uses).

I'm running this @localhost so won't be able to provide a link for this page. 
And I'm sorry if I've done any mistakes formatting this post or provide wrong info. Not really experienced at creating posts here in stack. :(

Any thoughts and ideas on this problem will be most welcome.

**Edit:** corrected that mistake as Evan suggested in the comments, where the calling was for `maps.google.com` and not `maps.googleapis.com`

**Edit2:** As Evan kept helping me on the comment section, I've made some additions to my code as follows.

The callback function that was returning a problem in console, was removed and I replaced it as a new callback for *initialize* function that appears on **common.js**.

```
var markers = [{(...)}];

function initialize() {(...)};
function initMap() {(...)};

var markers = [{(...)}];
function initMap2() {(...)};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); //This is the new callback for my maps
```

This did solved something, since the first map appeared. Still, there was still some error which console would point at:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined at initMap (common.js?a395:77) at initialize (common.js?a395:56)" pointing at this line of common.js: `for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {`.

I didn't get it. Just guessed that it had something to do with my markers code, since the first map appeared after the callback being made in common.js but with no marker.

Then, Evan pointed that if `i` was initialized globally, that error made sense. So he suggested changing the code to for `(let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {`, which did it for me. Adding it to both instances of markers in the code, made both maps appear properly and with markers.

Thanks for your help, Evan!

Comment: I'll look into this, but first let's rule out a script issue, i.e. you should call the JavaScript API using `https://maps.googleapis.com/` not `http://maps.google.com/`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I've changed that. The warning I get from chrome still remains, only pointing at `googleapis` now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, but I take it that the same issue persists then, correct? I'm not experienced in WP plugin development, but what I'm guessing may be happening here is that the callback function is called before JS runs it, can you try loading the script without a callback? What error (if any) do you get then?

Comment: Please remove the above comment ASAP as you're including your own private API key on a public site.

Comment: As for not getting any console errors now, is the issue fixed then? or is the initialize function not called at all? (note that you must call it somewhere in your code if the callback is removed otherwise the function will never run at all)

Comment: Also to add to the above re: api key, as an extra security measure please restrict it to your domain(s). Follow the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I should load that script (within  common.js) into functions.php using `plugin_dir_url`. Not sure if it would be the right way, since presspack is lying on routed scripts using webpack etc. :/

Comment: About the API Key, it is restricted already. But I'm willing to hide it from functions.php anyway. And no, the issue is not fixed yet. Working on a way to make a callback for that function somewhere else. `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Initialize);`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes that should work (although I believe it'd be lowercase `initialize`). I can load a google map using your API key so please double check that you've restricted it properly.

Comment: Well, it worked partially. One of the maps loaded ok! And that's great already. Now I gotta figure out how to load the second. I'm guessing that maybe changin' from one function (initialize) that loads another two "initMap" and "initMap2", I could probably make two DomListeners, one for each

Comment: Glad to hear one of your map loads now! What error do you get for the second one? You're already loading both maps when calling initialize, you don't need 2 page load DOM listeners.

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined at initMap (common.js?a395:77) at initialize (common.js?a395:56)" Reading the common right now. I guess it has something to do with my markers placement script, since it loads one map but it won't show the marker.

Comment: Just ran your JS code and both your markers are placed without problem. Also make sure that you removed `async defer` from your script if it's not using a callback.

Comment: Well, that´s just weird. I'm still not able to see both maps nor the marker in the first one. Removed the async defer. Thanks for reminding me. Also re-did the restricitions on Google Console. Guess it didn't saved it. **Edit:** Console points at this line: `for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {`

Comment: Actually the error makes sense if you haven't initialized `i` globally first. Did you? i.e. you're using `for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)`. Can you try `for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)`

Comment: It did it! Adding `let` to both lines `for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {` and `for (let i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {` not only showed the first marker, but also made the second map appear. Guess it was that. Thank you Evan for all the patience and good willing helping me out with all these sorts of things. Should I answer the Question with the whole solution or maybe the comments are enough?

Comment: Glad to hear! And happy to have been of help! :) We definitely should not leave this huge comment thread as is. Post your amended code in your OP and I'll answer your question with a full answer that summarizes the comment solutions.

Comment: Just answered with all our findings, and now i'm off to bed lol. Have a good one!

Comment: Was typing that edit. Thanks! Good night!

Comment: Loved your detailed edit. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the JavaScript API should be called via `https://maps.googleapis.com/`, not `http://maps.google.com/`.

The "initialize is not a function" scope error can be worked around by loading the Maps API script synchronously on page load, e.g. by using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)`, but in general the recommended approach is to load the API asynchronously via a callback:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Then there's an issue with both markers loops, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)`, as they're missing `i` initialization. Try using `for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)`.

You can find [here](https://jsbin.com/puwoqihobi/edit?html,console,output) a working jsbin that shows both your maps and markers loading successfully after the above code changes.